UV Texture Scaling
So, I'm using a procedural texture on my model. I'm using UV coordinates to place it. Trouble is I need to proceduraly scale that texture. I have the exact amount of scaling that texture needs in the face domain. The problem is that when I scale it up either in geometry or shader nodes, the UVs effectively overlap as depicted below.

That's effectively what they're doing when I need them to scale like below. Also I'm only scaling in the X direction on the UV so it should hypothetically be easier.

I have both the UVs and the scaling face data in geometry nodes, so it could hypothetically be fixed in either geometry nodes of shader nodes.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

I don't know the details of your UV dimensions, scaling factors etc. from your sketches, but the solution to this should be obvious: when you scale a column (as it seems) of UVs, they expand from the center to the left and right. If for example to the left are other UVs which get overlapped, you have to move the expanding UVs as much as they are overlapping in X direction to the right. Since you show nothing of how you implemented the scaling, I can just generally give the tip you not just have to scale, but to also move according to the scale and the resulting expansion.

Remap UV coordinates with some math nodes or something like Color Ramp:

RGB Curves also work:

And there are probably many other ways. It's basically just manipulating a range of vales from 0 to 1, so whatever method you come up with for that...
